# Multiple .save() in django FormView

Tags: python, django, formview

I'm trying to make it easier for users to input just two dates and then calculate days from them in form_valid(). Database model accepts each day as separate record.

```
def form_valid(self, form):

    time = form.cleaned_data['begin_time']
    end_time = form.cleaned_data['end_time']
    is_first_day = True

    while time + timedelta(hours=24) < end_time:
        data = form.save(commit=False)
        data.begin_time = time
        data.end_time = time + timedelta(hours=24)
        data.is_first_day = is_first_day
        data.save()
        is_first_day = False
        time = time + timedelta(hours=24)

    data = form.save(commit=False)
    data.settlement = settlement
    data.begin_time = time
    data.end_time = end_time
    data.is_first_day = is_first_day
    data.save()

    return super(FormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Unfortunately, only the last day has been saved. Is there any chance I can do data.save() multiple times in FormView without overriding it?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the difference between the first and last time that you are calculating?

Comment: I'm passing some other information in form, mostly the same for whole period. In rare situations users would be able to modify that later, but it's much less effort then specify each day separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't rely on `form.save()` and try to save different records. You should use `Model.objects.create()` to create new records.

Comment: So what's the advantage of form.save() over Model.objects.create() ? I suspect it was provided for some reason.